# can you compile a c# script without a csproj file in dotnet 5 and later

Tags: c#

I mean like in c++ you can do cl.exe main.cpp

I don't have really any reason to do that, just curious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming by "script" you mean "normal C# source file" then yes, absolutely, if `csc` is available to you:

Program.cs:

```cs
using System;
Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
```

Compile:

```bash
csc Program.cs
```

Run:

```bash
./Program.exe
```

Now, decompiling that, it looks like it's targeting .NET Framework rather than .NET Core by default, but I'd expect it to be feasible to change that if you really want to, by specifying a custom response file. It *does* make the latest C# features available to you, but if you use C# features that are only supported on later versions of .NET (e.g. default interface implementations) then I suspect you'd have to explicitly specify the appropriate standard libraries rather than using the default .NET Framework ones.

If `csc` isn't available to you as an executable, the DLL may still be available in the .NET SDK directory, under `Roslyn/bincore`.

For example, on my WSL2 Ubuntu installation, just trying to run `csc` fails, but the command below definitely invokes csc:

```bash
dotnet /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.202/Roslyn/bincore/csc.dll
```

The bad news is that trying to use that to just compile a standalone program requires providing library references etc - that's probably more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: this seems just for .net framework and not core

Comment: @MAR1: The version of csc I'm running isn't part of the .NET Framework (it's installed as part of MSBuild in VS2022), but I agree it's not in the .NET Core SDK. I don't have time to find details right now, but I'll update the answer briefly now and try to find how to install it on a "just .NET Core" system later. (Do you need it on Linux?)

Comment: i don't really need it i am just curious about how to do it, I am using windows

Comment: @MAR1: Okay, so if you're on Windows and you've got VS2022 installed, it should just work. What *exactly* do you mean by "and not core"? In terms of standard library defaults?

Comment: it doesnt support lateset c# versions

Comment: @MAR1: It really does. As an example, C# 10 introduced file-scoped namespace declarations, and they definitely work with csc - certainly on my box. Can you give a concrete example of what you're trying to do that fails with csc?

Answer (score 1):

No - but, for what you may be looking for, the `dotnet new console` command generates a default csproj that runs the Program.cs file that is also generated.
With the new(ish) [top level statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements) files, you can just insert a few `using`s and your script code, and just use `dotnet run`

If you're using an IDE, it'll run all the `dotnet` commands for you though

Comment: Links can be broken over time. So it quoting is better than just sharing links.

Answer (score 0):

Yes C# has a Scripting concept(.csx). It also has a REPL (csi.exe)

References : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/january/essential-net-csharp-scripting